# Magento 1.9 Magmi/MAP Pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, database, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, magmi

We're uploading 3k+ products via **Magmi** and have run scripts to create rules and exclude certain categories.  We have a separate .csv with MAP pricing for certain SKUs.  Thoughts on how to apply the MAP .csv to those SKUs from the original product run?  And avoid changing to MAP pricing product by product.

***MAP pricing means - Minimum Advertised Price - manufacturer's restrictions on the lowest** we can actually advertise the price.

Workaround - MAP pricing feature should hide the price if it falls below the given MAP price til user adds it to cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only the products you need referenced by the SKU. The columns in your CSV would be

```
SKU, map_price, msrp_enable, msrp_display_actual_price_type
```

with the proper values